# Python read from file line by line

Tags: python, sockets

I want to use a file instead of "192.168.171.135" to run lots of ip's.
And also port range instead of 22
How is it possible?

```
# Import socket module 
import socket            

# Create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()  

# Define the port on which you want to connect 
port = 22               

try:
# connect to the server on local computer 
    s.connect(('192.168.171.135', port)) 
    print ("192.168.171.135:", port, " is open.")
except socket.gaierror:
    print ("There was an error resolving the host")
    sys.exit()
# receive data from the server 
print (s.recv(1024) ) 
# close the connection 
s.close()
```

Comment: Here's how to read a file line by line in python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pyfiglet 
import sys 
import socket 
from datetime import datetime 

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("YIGIT's Scanner") 
print(ascii_banner) 

print("-" * 50)
print("Scanning started at:" + str(datetime.now())) 
print("-" * 50) 

try:
    with open("/home/kali/BAA/hostnames.txt") as fp: # You must change the filepath
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for ip in lines:
            target = socket.gethostbyname(ip.strip())
            print("-" * 20)
            print("Scanning IP: ", target)
         # This will scan ports between 1 to 65,535 
            for port in range(1,100): 
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
                socket.setdefaulttimeout(1) 
              
            # Returns an error indicator 
                result = s.connect_ex((target,port)) 
                if result == 0:
                    print(target, ":" ,"Port ", port, "is open")
                s.close() 
          
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        print("\n Exitting Program !!!!") 
        sys.exit() 
except socket.gaierror: 
        print("\n Hostname Could Not Be Resolved !!!!") 
        sys.exit() 
except socket.error: 
        print("\ Server not responding !!!!") 
        sys.exit()
```